# Failing OpenMVG installation using VS 2017 on windows

Tags: c++, cmake, computer-vision, release, visual-studio-2017

I've been trying to install OpenMVG on windows 10 using this guide.
the build isn't passing.

https://github.com/openMVG/openMVG/blob/master/BUILD

first i built a vs 2017 compatible project using CMake 
then compiled it using vs 2017.

here is the build output.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Release Win32 -----
1>-- Install configuration: "Release"
1>CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:31 (file):
1>  file INSTALL cannot make directory "C:/Program Files
1>  (x86)/openMVG/include/openMVG_dependencies": No such file or directory
1>
1>
1>-- Installing: C:/Program Files (x86)/openMVG/include/openMVG_dependencies
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "INSTALL.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
2>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
3>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: cxsparse, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
3>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
4>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: fast, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
4>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
5>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: lemon (OpenMVG\3rdParty\lemon\lemon), Configuration: Release Win32 ------
5>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
6>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: lib_clp (OpenMVG\3rdParty\lib_clp\lib_clp), Configuration: Release Win32 ------
6>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
7>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_features, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
7>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
8>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: stlplus, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
8>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
9>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: zlib, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
9>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
10>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_numeric, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
10>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
11>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: ceres (OpenMVG\3rdParty\ceres\ceres), Configuration: Release Win32 ------
11>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
12>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: lib_CoinUtils (OpenMVG\3rdParty\lib_CoinUtils\lib_CoinUtils), Configuration: Release Win32 ------
12>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
13>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: lib_Osi (OpenMVG\3rdParty\lib_Osi\lib_Osi), Configuration: Release Win32 ------
13>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
14>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: lib_OsiClpSolver (OpenMVG\3rdParty\lib_OsiClpSolver\lib_OsiClpSolver), Configuration: Release Win32 ------
14>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
15>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: tiff, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
15>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
16>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: png, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
16>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
17>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_system, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
17>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
18>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_multiview, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
18>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
19>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: jpeg, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
19>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
20>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_matching, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
20>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
21>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_image, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
21>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
22>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: vlsift, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
22>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
23>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_kvld, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
23>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
24>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_matching_image_collection, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
24>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
25>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: easyexif, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
25>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
26>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_pano_converter, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
26>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
27>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_robustHomography_guided, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
27>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
28>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_robust_estimation_Homography, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
28>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
29>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_multiview_robustHomography, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
29>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
30>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: main_svgSample, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
30>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
31>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_features_affine, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
31>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
32>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_exif_Parsing, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
32>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
33>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_multiview_test_data, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
33>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
34>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_cameras_undistoBrown, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
34>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
35>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_features_kvld, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
35>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
36>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_features_siftPutative, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
36>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
37>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_geodesy_show_exif_gps_position, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
37>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
38>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_image_matching, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
38>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
39>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_main_features_repeatability_dataset, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
39>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
40>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_multiview_robustFundamental, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
40>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
41>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_multiview_robustFundamental_guided, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
41>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
42>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_lInftyComputerVision, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
42>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
43>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sfm, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
43>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
44>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_ListMatchingPairs, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
44>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
45>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_ColHarmonize, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
45>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
46>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_ComputeFeatures, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
46>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
47>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_ComputeMatches, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
47>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
48>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_ComputeSfM_DataColor, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
48>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
49>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_ComputeStructureFromKnownPoses, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
49>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
50>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_ConvertList, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
50>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
51>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_ConvertSfM_DataFormat, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
51>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
52>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_ExportCameraFrustums, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
52>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
53>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_ExportUndistortedImages, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
53>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
54>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_FrustumFiltering, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
54>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
55>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_GlobalSfM, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
55>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
56>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_IncrementalSfM, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
56>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
57>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_SfMInit_ImageListing, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
57>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
58>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_SfM_Localization, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
58>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
59>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_evalQuality, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
59>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
60>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_exportKeypoints, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
60>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
61>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_exportMatches, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
61>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
62>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_exportTracks, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
62>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
63>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_geodesy_registration_to_gps_position, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
63>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
64>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_openMVG2CMPMVS, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
64>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
65>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_openMVG2MESHLAB, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
65>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
66>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_openMVG2MVE2, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
66>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
67>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_openMVG2MVSTEXTURING, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
67>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
68>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_openMVG2NVM, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
68>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
69>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_openMVG2PMVS, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
69>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
70>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_main_openMVG2openMVS, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
70>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
71>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_multiview_robustEssential, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
71>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
72>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_multiview_robustEssential_ba, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
72>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
73>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: openMVG_sample_multiview_robustEssential_spherical, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
73>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
74>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
74>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 73 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 73 skipped ==========
```

and there is no deploy option enabled in the configuration manager for ALL_BUILD and INSTALL.

[image: Screenshot of the configuration manager]

[image: Error message after compilation]